# how to Find row wise maximum value IN ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Table Given

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 25 | 30 |
| 2 | 11 | 10 | 11 |
| 3 | 5 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 10 | 2 | 5 |
| 5 | 12 | 15 | 10 |

Desire Output

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | O/P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 25 | 30 | 30 |
| 2 | 11 | 10 | 11 | 11 |
| 3 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 10 | 2 | 5 | 10 |
| 5 | 12 | 15 | 10 | 15 |

Answer (score 3):

Use the scalar `GREATEST` function:

```sql
SELECT C1, C2, C3, C4, GREATEST(C1, C2, C3, C4) AS "O/P"
FROM yourTable;
```